# draw custom drawable in android

Tags: android, android-drawable

How can I draw the custom drawable as attached in the image?

[image]

I don't the complete code, just steps how should I proceed would be sufficient and any links to advanced custom drawable tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to have a custom drawable for this. Simple TableLayout would work for you. And also learn how to use nine patch drawables http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Thanks you. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. Any more help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented it using layer-list. Anyone needs to see the code.. Message me.

```
<!-- Colored rectangle -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke android:color="@color/color_black" />

        <solid android:color="@color/col_gray_light" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="50dp"
    android:left="-25dp"
    android:right="-105dp"
    android:top="-120dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/color_white" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="63dp"
    android:right="-15dp"
    android:top="-40dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/color_white" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="-40dp"
    android:right="-20dp"
    android:top="60dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="-45" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/color_white" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/help/draw9patch.html) images as background.

Here is a nice tool you can use online [Simple Nine-patch Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

Here is how you would achieve it

- Use a White background for your main layout view (Table View for example)
- create two 9-patch images for the grey boxes. One for the left side and other for the right side
- For the boxes that must be rendered grey use the appropriate 9-path background (left or right).

Comment: Thanks you. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: How have you utilized it? Whats exactly not working ?